# Read a dynamically updated txt file with Jquery

Tags: jquery, eclipse, jsp

I am writing an application where a Servlet activates a crawler and writes the URL's of interest to a txt file. Then I want to read this txt file (line by line) and append to my JSP. I am using the following Jquery:

```
// LOAD file and split line by line and append divs
        $.get('./crawlFiles/urls.txt', function(data) {
            setTimeout(data, 3000);
            var lines = data.split("\n");
            $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
                $('#reviewList').append('<div><a href="'+ elem +'">' + elem + '</a></div>');
            });
        });
```

Without the setTimeout() I can read the file, but it shows old information (I have to reload the project in Eclipse in order to get the new information). I found by searching this site that setTimeout() should do the work, but that gives me nothing on the screen.

How can I read the txt file with the newly added information?

Answer (score 3):

seems a cache problem?
Guess you should set the cache config to no(like above):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: I already have this in startup, so that does not fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Upon requesting  just put randomized number as a query string , ./crawlFiles/urls.txt?rand=randomnumber.

I like to use DDMMYYYYHHMMSS as randomized number, its always unique.

Comment: [Careful with this!](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)